# MATLAB runs prior iterations of file

Tags: matlab

#### Summary: MATLAB runs an earlier version of my code, despite having saved the new version.

When I run my code, MATLAB seems to run an older version of it. For example, I changed the print statement from "What is the name of the vector you wish to analyze?" to  "Hello. How are you?", but it still runs the previous version of the code, despite the fact that I saved the file.
[image: Image of problem]
I have tried deleting all the files in the MATLAB "Current Folders" directory, and even opening new files for every small iteration of my code, but to no avail. I've tried searching for resolution to similar errors online, but this does not seem to have been documented previously. The only resource that even refers to this online seems to be this [question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/799507-matlab-seems-to-be-using-an-old-version-of-the-code), whose only resolution was that "The error message was misleading."

I would greatly appreciate any help. I am new to MATLAB, so please pardon any naive mistakes.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to make it clearer what command you are typing and, if possible, give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue to better allow us to help you.

Comment: run `clear functions` to clear all cached function definitions before re-running. Also use `which VeryImportantFile -all` to check there aren't multiple definitions on your path

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, there are two copies of the code, the one you are editing and the one you are running.

If the code you are trying to run is called "mycode", try typing `which mycode`.  This will tell you the location of the code version that you are running.  I would also recommend closing the editor window and typing `edit mycode`, which will open that version.

Note: From the screenshot, it appears that you are running MATLAB through a web browser and I don't know how that handles files.